# How to get matplotlib to use fonts in home directory?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I downloaded some `.ttf` fonts and placed them in my home directory in `~/.fonts`. When I run

```
matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
```

these fonts show up in the list (by path). I can also run

```
matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(<path>).get_name()
```

and get back the name of the fonts, for example "Impact".

But when I try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.text(0,0,'Hello',fontname='Impact')
```

It says the font family is not found. Fonts in the public `/usr/share/` area work as expected.

How can I make matplotlib know where to look when making the actual call?

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up with is to use `fontproperties` directly.

This gives a list of paths, including home directory fonts:

```
matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
```

For any given file path this give the fontproperties:

```
prop = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(<path>)
```

The size can be changed in this object, but boldness and italics are built in.

You can use it as is:

```
plt.text(0,0,'Hello',fontproperties=prop)
```

This is okay, but not ideal since you'll just have a list of paths and can't simply specify you want Arial bold italic or something. It wouldn't take too much work to build up a dictionary or something though, since this info is in the properties.